# Error sending email with AWS SES & Lambda node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I create Lambda function in AWS and use SES NodeJs to sending an email. At first, I was put my code in my localhost and it works very well and I had receive an email from it, but when I try put in Lambda, it does not give any respone and there is no email that I get in my email inbox.

Here is error message from Lambda :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2016-08-30T07:47:13.46Z afca06-6e85-a522-471b6c7 Task timed out after 20.00 seconds"
}
```

is there something wrong with my code if I want to put it in Lambda? or is there something that I missing code? or is there any way to solve it? Thanks for any help!

Here is my code :

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

  var aws = require('aws-sdk');

  var ses = new aws.SES({
      accessKeyId: 'AKIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      secretAccessKey: 't1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      region: 'us-west-2'  
  });

  // send to
  var to = ['my_email@gmail.com'];

  // verified SES account
  var from = 'my.verifiedmail@gmail.com';

  ses.sendEmail( { 
    Source: from, 
      Destination: { 
        ToAddresses: to 
      },
    Message: {
        Subject: {
            Data: 'A Message To You'
        },
        Body: {
           Text: {
               Data: 'Stop your messing around'
           }
        }
    }
  }
  , function(err, data) {
      if(err) {

        //console.log(err);
        context.done(null, { err });

      }
      else {

        //console.log(data);
        context.done(null, { data });

      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Did you try to extend Lambda function timeout threshold?

Comment: Chien : I was solve this problem. The problem is when I use VPC, SES didn't work if I use VPC on SES configuration. When I remove it, SES working well. cheerss!